# Splitting this string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split the string `"1 + 2 / 3 * 4 - 5 "` to display `"+" "/" "*" "-"` to be saved into an array to, the same to be done to the number, so that I call each number and op' into a function to calculate it in BODMAS`(/*+-)` order.

The string can be longer and shorter as it is a user input calculation.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var str = "1+2/3*4-5";
        var res = str.split([0-9]);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You probably want a regular expression, those generally start and end with `/`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9k9v09ds/

Comment: I would look for a calculator parser such as...http://jorendorff.github.io/calc/docs/calculator-parser.html

Comment: Do you need something that handles other operators, like `^`, named variables like in the expression `2x + 3 = 0`, or non-integers like `2.3`?

Comment: I'm detecting XY problem here but need more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called the `myFunction` function. Use a non-maching character at the front, `[^0-9]`. It will match anything that is not a number. Don't use `split`. `split` doesn't recognize [0-9] as a splitting character. Use the [string.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method instead. It will return an array containing every match.

```js
    function myFunction() {
        var str = "1+2/3*4-5";
  var match=str.match(/[^0-9]+/g);
        
      for(i=0;i<match.length;i++){
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML+=match[i]+'</br>';
   }
    }
 myFunction();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do a:

```
str.split(/\d+/)
```

to get the symbols and

```
str.split(/\D+/)
```

to get the numbers